# xargs respect wildcards in searches

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a file called file1.txt:

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
...
```

I wanted to use xargs to check if some files exist farther into the file system like this:

```
 cat file1.txt | xargs -i ls  /projects/analysis7/{}/meta_bwa/hg19a/*varFilter 2>/dev/null
```

But xargs never seems smart enough to expand the *.  ie, it never finds the files even when they would match the pattern (if the * was expanded).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to add `sh -c`:

```
 cat file1.txt | xargs -i sh -c 'ls  /projects/analysis7/{}/meta_bwa/hg19a/*varFilter' 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Just to note, this works when the wildcards are found in the `file1.txt` as well.