# How to pass directory name from find to grep through xargs?

Tags: linux

```
.
├── AAA
│   └── 01.txt
├── AAA_X
│   └── 03.txt
├── BBB
│   └── 02.txt
└── BBB_X
    └── 04.txt



$ find . -not -name \*_X -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I {} grep 'Hello' {}/\*.txt
grep: ./*.txt: No such file or directory
grep: ./AAA/*.txt: No such file or directory            << Why failed here?
grep: ./BBB/*.txt: No such file or directory

$ grep 'Hello' AAA/*.txt
Hello
```

Question> How can I pass the directory names to `grep` from `find` with `xargs`?

Comment: You're passing the directory name just fine. The problem is that `xargs` doesn't run the command through a shell, so nothing expands the `*` wildcard.

Comment: Why don't you just use `find . -name '*.txt'`?

Comment: @Barmar, I have updated my OP to illustrate why I want to filter the directories first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `xargs` doesn't execute the command through the shell.

You should use `-name '*.txt'` to get the files directly in the `find` command. To exclude the `*_X` directories, you can use `-prune`:

```
find . -type d -name '*_X' -prune -o -name '*.txt' -exec grep 'Hello' {} +
```

Comment: $ find . -not -name \*_X -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I {} sh -c "grep Hello {}/*.txt -l"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087407/xargs-respect-wildcards-in-searches

Comment: @q0987 That won't do the right thing if the directory name has spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use --exclude with grep?

```
grep --exclude=*_X/*.txt Hello */*.txt
```